# When i push into github from vs code it shows me the wrong user even though i have signed in with the right account

Tags: github

I am having a issue every time I push code into GitHub:

- I have this account [image: account]
- and this is what it shows after I do a commit:
  [image]

This is a name or nickname I have never used, and this shows for private repositories and public repositories as well.

After doing some research, I have removed Windows credentials of GitHub and VSCode to make sure that the issue does not stand there:
[image: Windows Credentials]

It did not resolve the issue.
I have tried the command to remove all credentials and add them again, I added them again but the issue still persists.

For some reason, every time I make a commit, unless I upload directly the code from `github.com`, it will show it with the wrong user as push.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at your origin url? You may be pushing to "<username>@github.com/<repo>".

EDIT: I believe git also has an "user.name" and "user.email" that are added to your commits, I think this is set in your general git config but I may be wrong and it could be repo dependent.

Comment: I have pushed directly to the link, 
It does the same issue even when I commit and push from source control from vs code

Answer (score 0):

Credentials are use to authenticate to GitHub, which check if your account (identified by the credentials) has the right to access/push to your remote repository.

This has nothing to do with commit authorship, which is only set by a local `git config --global user.name` or `user.email`.

Check first those settings, adjust them (especially the email one), and make/push another commit, to confirm they are properly displayed (with the right account)